# Find when was last SP\CU was installed on SQL Server using T-SQL query or powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

I need to find when was last SP\CU was installed on SQL Server using T-SQL query or PowerShell.

Currently we can see it in

1. control panel--> installed updates
   AND
2. C:\setupbootstrap\summary\logs

I have so many servers and  I don't want to login to each server and need some query for the same. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: maybe `SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceLastUpdateDateTime')`? "Returns the date and time that the Resource database was last updated." so would be dependent on there being nothing else that can bump that and on all CUs bumping that though.

Comment: I am afraid that correct. As When I check the date in control panel its different date.

Comment: that's a shame!